# Copying first line of text to another text file

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

**Before:**

file1

```
123
456
```

file2

```
foo
testing
```

**After:**

file1

```
123
456
```

file2

```
foo
testing 123
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the content you gave in the example Here's what I suggest to you

```
echo -en " `head -1 file1`" >> file2
```

Comment: it would append after the last line of the file2 instead of appending to the last line...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
sed -i "$ s/$/ $(head -1 file1)/" file2
testing 123
```

- `$` edit the last line of the file.
- `s/$` Substitute the EOL with `$(head -1 file1)`, which is the first line of the file1.

Comment: This works for the given example, but will fail if the first line if `file2` contains characters like single quote, slash or backslash

Answer (score 0):

The task is less obvious than is looks at the first sight.

Either you use the Code by Slyx and remove the unwanted newline with `sed $!N;$s/\n//;P;D` afterwards or you find a string which is known not to be part of both files, let's say `=snip=` and do

```
sed '1h;1,/=snip=/d;$G;s/\n/ /' file1 <( echo =snip=) file2
```

The output can be piped to another file, then copied to `file2` (even if your `sed` flavour has option `-i` this won't work when using parts of two files).

What does the code do?

- `1h` stores line 1 in the hold space (the "clipboard" of `sed`) to append it later
- `1,/=snip=/d` deletes everything from line 1 to our marker line, so only `file2` will be printed
- `$G` appends the saved line from the hold space for the last line (`$`)
- `s/\n/ /` replaces an embedded newline by a whitespace. This will only happen in the last line after we appended the hold space
- `file1 <( echo =snip=) file2` are the files streamed to `sed`: first `file1` to extract the first line, then a virtual file containing `=snip=` to know when file 1 ends, finally `file2`

Actually, a nice task to learn `sed` tricks.

Answer (score 0):

There's `ed`:

```
ed file2 <<END
1a
$(head -n 1 file1)
.
1s/$/ /
1,2j
wq
END
```

But awk may be clearer:

```
awk -v "f1=$(head -n1 file1):" 'NR == 1 {$0 = $0 FS f1} 1' file2
```

That does not save file2 inplace. For that you can do, with GNU awk

```
gawk -i inplace -v "f1=$(head -n1 file1):" 'NR == 1 {$0 = $0 FS f1} 1' file2
```

or with any awk:

```
awk -v ... file2 > tmpfile2 && mv tmpfile2 file2
```

Another gawk option

```
gawk '
    FNR == 1 { if (NR == FNR) {f1 = $0; nextfile} else {$0 = $0 FS f1} }
    {print}
' file1 file2
```